# How can I fetch data by Tag number in Firebase?

Tags: java, android

users
-LEeFjPRnM2pFpBJkMGx

- cityStr: "Pune"
- strArea1: "wadagaon "
- strDogAge1: "three days "
- strDogGender1: "male "
- strDogName1: "dodo"
- strDriverContact1: "1234567890"
- strDriverName1: "koko"
- strIdentification1: "black "
- strLocation1: "wadagaon "
- strMediCondi1: "good"
- strPickupDate1: "13/6/2018"
- strTagNumber1: "125"
- strVehicalPickup1: "1234"

This is my Firebase data. I want to fetch data by Tag number.That is when I type Tag number - 125 it should return me all data of it.How can I do this?

Here is my android code :-

```
Select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           mFirebaseDatabase.addChildEventListener(newChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is unreadable. Please clean it up and format your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query q;
String city;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    q =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("strTagNumber1").equalTo("125");

    Select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                   if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        // You will get the details of user with tag number - 125 
                        // eg-
                        city = dataSnapshot.child("cityStr").getValue();
                    } 
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: I hope this have worked for u. So plz accept & upvote the answer which can be helpful for others too.